# How to change the max value for input type number on HTML5 with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need change the max attribute of an input element with JavaScript. For example:

```
<input type="number" name="miname" min="0" max="MyVar" value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 24):

You can assign an id to your input :

```
<input id="myInput" type="number" name="miname" min="0" max="MyVar" value="0"/>
```

then access it via javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.setAttribute("max",100); // set a new value;
```

Note you can also access it directly if your input is in a form

```
document.formName.miname.setAttribute("max",newValue);
```

Comment: Thanks! you know howte reset value to 0 with the chanfe attr max?

Comment: `document.formName.miname.value = 0;` or `input.value=0;` depending on which method you chose.

Comment: Please take time to accept the answer that helped you solve your problem. Click on the **Check mark** on the left of the answer. You can do so for all the answers that helped you previously

Comment: **upvote @ibu thanks for the help. Sorry he won't accept your answer :(

Comment: @mrchameleon, glad it was useful to you. Don't worry, 3 years later I learned to live with it.

Comment: Thank You @Ibu your first block of JavaScript helped me beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

sharing the angular way of doing it. Use [attr.max].

```
<input matInput type="number" min="0"  [attr.max]="totalOrders"  placeholder="Total Skybridge Orders" formControlName="totalSkybridge" (change)="onTotalSkybridgeOrders($event)"
```